# How to convert database query builder into Eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I need to convert a database query builder into an Eloquent model. I'm using the plugin https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable and it requires an Eloquent model.

```php
<?php

$payments = DB::table('users')
    ->select('orders.id', 'users.id', 'users.name', 'orders.amount', 'orders.created_at', 'orders.updated_at')
    ->join('patients', 'users.id', '=', 'patients.user_id')
    ->join('orders', 'patients.id', '=', 'orders.patient_id')
    ->where('users.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
    ->orWhere('users.email', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
    ->get();
```

Comment: define models, and their relationships and then it will become easy as this: `User::with(['patients','orders'])->where('users.name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->orWhere('users.email','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
            ->get();`, if you need more help, please post your models with their relationships

Answer (score 0):

call your model inside  your controller method.

```
$companyObj = new modelname();
$userDetail = $companyObj->model_method_name($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

try declaring eloquent relationship in your respective model as given below:

```
    class Users extends Model {
     public function patients(){
          return this->hasOne('App\Patients', 'user_id', 'id')->with('orders');
     }
    }

   class Patients extends Model {
       public function orders() {
           return this->hasMany('App\Orders', 'patient_id', 'id')->select('id', 'amount', 'created_at', 'updated_at');
       }
   }
```

now call these relationships in eloquent query in Users repository/controller:

```
$payments = $this->getModel()->select('id', 'name')->with('patients')->where('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->orWhere('email','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->get();
```